# is there any way to abort jquery promise function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code snippet in an AJAX `success` handler

```
if (response.responsecode == 1) {
  $(".model-div").show();
  $("#model-title-bar").show("");   
  $("#model-title-bar").delay(4500).fadeOut().promise().done(function(){
   $(".model-div").hide();
  });
}
```

Now I want to perform `$(".model-div").hide();` as well as `$("#model-title-bar").hide()` which is part of promise function and will auto hide after 4500 ms.

Now I want to hide `$("#model-title-bar")` as soon as click observed any where on browser , irrespective of time it should be any value < 4500 ms.

Answer (score 0):

This link should be helpful: [deferred.rejectwith](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.rejectwith/)

It will allow you to reject a deferred object. Additionally, you can pass the context and arguments as the failCallback will be called.

Answer (score 0):

I think a function [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) can help you:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $("#model-title-bar").stop();
});
```